# delphi 10 seattle update installed?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

This month we purchased the upgrade from XE to Delphi 10 Seattle.
I used the installation link in the registration email. Later i saw that there is now an update 1 available that requires a reinstall.

Now im in doubt if the installer i used orginally included update 1 or not.
The about screen in Delphi 10 Seatle shows 'no updates installed' and in the lower part of the about screen 'Build 0' so this suggests its the older version without the update.
But it would be a lot of work to reinstall everying especially all the components, so i would like to be sure before i start from scratch.

So the question: Can someone tell me how i can determine if i have update 1 installed or not?

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Comment: Did you buy a subscription update or not?

Comment: yes we included the one year subscription

Comment: I also entered the account for this subscription in the installer. So i expected i was installing the latest version. But since the about screen does not show anything about the update im now in doubt.

Comment: It sounds like you've already concluded that you do not have any updates installed. Typically, the very first thing you do when installing any software (especially a paid one) is to check for updates before proceeding. The same goes with Windows itself. Delphi should have actually asked you if you would like to check for updates as soon as it finished installing.

Comment: `no updates installed` is pretty clear - the only reason to not believe this is wishful thinking.  You must reinstall.  Such is the joy of Embarcadero's update process.

Comment: Based on answers i will do a full reinstall of an image with update 1. (just to clearyfy: I did check for updates with the installer during first time installation and it did download several update, so i assumed it would be up to date)

Comment: For the last few releases, there have been no meaningful service-pack releases that installed without requiring an uninstall. The only "in place updates" that have been shipped were some tiny hotfixes. The normal "Update 1" type of update (basically a service pack) has required full uninstall and reinstall. The update isn't an update.  I know. Weird.

Comment: Our company just purchased Delphi 10, and when we received the email with the license and download info, there are two downloads: One of them is for the original release, and the second link is for the installation with Update 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already answered your question.... "no updates installed" means that you don't have update 1 installed.

Select that you want to keep your registry entries during uninstall, then you don't need to reinstall your components.

Comment: I definitely wouldn't trust that. I would at least perform a rebuild / reinstall of everything once more to be sure they reflect any changes between the versions.

Comment: There are no changes in update 1 that require you to change any current user registry settings.

Comment: @WarrenP I meant any third-party libraries which may have already been compiled/installed into the IDE, which OP mentions. I would rebuild them anyway.

Comment: There are no interface changes, and other than 64 bit, there are no compiler code-gen changes. 64 bit packages may need to be rebuilt.

Comment: I reinstalled Delphi 10 Seattle from an image with update 1 included from scratch last night. And i can confirm that now the about screen in delphi shows it has update 1 installed. So i was definitly running the version without the update before the reinstall. Thanks everyone for all the advice and assistance.