# How to tell if RAD Studio 10 Seattle Update 1 has been installed?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I Uninstalled RAD Studio 10 Seattle in preparation for upgrading to Update 1. I just reinstalled RAD Studio 10 Seattle but I don't remember if I ran the Update 1 ISO or the original ISO.

Is there a quick way to tell if RAD Studio 10 Seattle Update 1 has been installed?

Comment: Help -> [About Embarcadero® Delphi](https://helloacm.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/delphi-10-about.jpg)

Comment: also... http://stackoverflow.com/q/34265645/327083

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]Look at the "Help->About" screen.

"Installed Updates:"  (will say)

> Delphi 10 Seattle and C++Builder 10 Seattle Subscription Update 1